# Error installing the mongo-edu on mac

Tags: python, macos, mongodb, npm, nodes

I'm trying to install [mongo-edu](https://github.com/przemyslawpluta/mongo-edu) on my mac without success.
Does anyone have some solution for it?

```
$ sudo npm install mongo-edu -g
```

Error log file:

```
15129 silly install printInstalled
15130 verbose stack Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, chmod '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/mongo-edu/node_modules/youtube-dl/bin/youtube-dl'
15130 verbose stack     at Error (native)
15131 verbose cwd /Users/Biruel
15132 error Darwin 15.5.0
15133 error argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "mongo-edu" "-g"
15134 error node v6.2.1
15135 error npm  v3.9.6
15136 error path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/mongo-edu/node_modules/youtube-dl/bin/youtube-dl
15137 error code ENOENT
15138 error errno -2
15139 error syscall chmod
15140 error enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, chmod '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/mongo-edu/node_modules/youtube-dl/bin/youtube-dl'
15141 error enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, chmod '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/mongo-edu/node_modules/youtube-dl/bin/youtube-dl'
15141 error enoent This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
15141 error enoent and is related to npm not being able to find a file.
15142 verbose exit [ -2, true ]
```

My Versions (Mac El Capitan) and...

```
$ Python3 -V && Python -V && node -v && npm -v
Python 3.5.1
Python 2.7.11    ps: native on mac
v6.2.1           ps: node
3.9.6            ps: npm
```

Permissions (chmod & chown).
I already to the following to guarantee my access permissions

```
$ sudo chmod 755 -R /usr/local/lib
$ sudo chown -R Biruel /usr/local/lib
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is a issue with youtube downloader

[see this](https://github.com/przemyslawpluta/mongo-edu/issues/77)

that menas youtube downloader package makes a noise :(